# Round SQL Time to nearest hour if 1min away from nearest hour

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I would like to be about to round SQL Time to the nearest hour if the time value is 1min away from the nearest hour. (Time is in 24 hour clock format)

For instance

```
23:59 - > 00:00
11:30 - > 11:30
03:59 - > 04:00
01:15 - > 01:15
12:59 - > 13:00
```

This is what I was able to do so far, but it is only rounding to the nearest 1min.

```
declare @t time 
declare @t2 time
set @t = '23:59:00.0000000';
set @t2 = '23:30:00.0000000';

select cast(dateadd(millisecond, 29999, @t) as smalldatetime) as T1, cast(dateadd(millisecond, 29999, @t2) as smalldatetime) as T2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a decision if you try to add one minute and then test the result:

```
SELECT 
    cast(dateadd(millisecond, 29999, @t) as smalldatetime) as T1, 
    cast(dateadd(millisecond, 29999, @t2) as smalldatetime) as T2
    ,CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(CAST(DATEADD(MINUTE, 1, @t) as nvarchar(15)),4,2) = '00' THEN DATEADD(MINUTE, 1, @t) ELSE @t END
    ,CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(CAST(DATEADD(MINUTE, 1, @t2) as nvarchar(15)),4,2) = '00' THEN DATEADD(MINUTE, 1, @t2) ELSE @t2 END
```

Comment: Very elegant solution, by adding 1min to the value to test if minutes equals nearest hour. thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a strange requirement -- just getting rid of one particular minute out of 60.  But a `case` statement should do what you want:

```
select (case when datepart(hour, time) = 59
             then dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, @t) + 1, 0)
             else @t
        end)
```

Answer (score 0):

use this idea:

```
select case when datepart(hh,dateadd(minute,1,convert(time,'10:59'))) <> datepart(hh,convert(time,'10:59')) then dateadd(minute,1,convert(time,'10:59'))
else convert(time,'10:59') end
```

Answer (score 0):

This uses a case statement to check if the minutes (not hours @GordonLinoff :) is 59 or 0, and if so, returns the time rounded off to the nearest hour. Else it just returns the time. Here is some sample code

```
declare @t table (t time);
insert @t (t) values 
('22:58:00'),
('22:58:30'),
('22:59:00'),
('22:59:30'),
('23:00:00'),
('23:00:30'),
('23:01:00'),
('23:01:30')

select 
  t, 

  -- just return the time rounded to the nearest hour
  cast (dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, dateadd(mi, 30, t)), 0) as time) as NearestHour,

  -- return the time rounded to the nearest hour ONLY IF IT"S WITHIN ONE MINUTE OF THE HOUR
  case when datepart (minute, t) in (0, 59)
        then cast (dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, dateadd(mi, 30, t)), 0) as time)
        else t 
  end as Rounded

from @t
```

And here is the result:

```
t                NearestHour      Rounded
---------------- ---------------- ----------------
22:58:00.0000000 23:00:00.0000000 22:58:00.0000000
22:58:30.0000000 23:00:00.0000000 22:58:30.0000000
22:59:00.0000000 23:00:00.0000000 23:00:00.0000000
22:59:30.0000000 23:00:00.0000000 23:00:00.0000000
23:00:00.0000000 23:00:00.0000000 23:00:00.0000000
23:00:30.0000000 23:00:00.0000000 23:00:00.0000000
23:01:00.0000000 23:00:00.0000000 23:01:00.0000000
23:01:30.0000000 23:00:00.0000000 23:01:30.0000000
```

Comment: this is a neat solution as well. however I would like if its 58min to stay at 58. only if it is 1min away from the hour will it be rounded up.

Comment: Mmm - please look at the last column (Rounded) - does it give what you need? Please check for 23:01 as well?

Comment: ah sorry, missed that last column. rounded works perfectly. very nice solution thank you